# URL redirect on homepage of wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm using a particular wordpress theme (Pluto) to make a site. When I go to my domain - [www.tastersclubwhiskeyofthemonth.com](http://www.tastersclubwhiskeyofthemonth.com) , the homepage displays no content until you hit one of the menu items.

How can I get my homepage to default to a specific menu item @ www.tastersclubwhiskeyofthemonth.com/**#whiskey-of-the-month**

I tried using the typical HTML redirect, but it doesn't work with my site - maybe because all my urls have # after the .com, or maybe because it's a wordpress site?:
`<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.tastersclubwhiskeyofthemonth.com/#whiskey-of-the-month">` but it doesn't work.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a htaccess mod rewrite rule. Add this to your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^something\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://.something.com/#something2 [R=301,L]
```